# Azure AD App Registration for Multi tenant and Personal accounts using powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell

Is there anyway to achieve creating Azure AD App Registration for Multi tenant and Personal accounts using powershell. Nothing in this document helps me do that https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/new-azureadapplication?view=azureadps-2.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, as mentioned by Allen, AD App type property is managed by `-SignInAudience` parameter, but when you use `New-AzureADApplication` with `-SignInAudience`, it will give an error `Property 'signInAudience' is read-only and cannot be set`, as `New-AzureADApplication` essentially calls the old [Azure AD Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/api/api-catalog).

To solve the issue, you could call the [Microsoft Graph - Create application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-applications?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) manually in powershell as mentioned by Allen, you could also this new command [`New-AzureADMSApplication`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/new-azureadmsapplication?view=azureadps-2.0) , it calls the Microsoft Graph directly.

Make sure your `AzureAD` powershell module is not too old, then use the command below.

```
New-AzureADMSApplication -DisplayName "joytest678" -SignInAudience "AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount"
```

[image]

Check in the portal:

[image]

Comment: Hi @joy thanks! I have installed AzureAD module but still errors out saying, The term 'New-AzureADMSApplication' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet any help?

Comment: @s-a-n Update your module to the latest version with `Update-Module -Name AzureAD -Force`.

Comment: unfortunately doesnt seem to work for me. it here anyway you can share the AzureAD module version?

Comment: @s-a-n My version is `2.0.2.130`, see https://i.stack.imgur.com/3swoI.png

Comment: For some reason I see in Get-InstalledModules but not in Get-Module, is there any otherway I load the modules?

Comment: @s-a-n If you already used the AzureAD module command, it will be imported to the powershell session automatically, if not, you can also use `Import-Module -Name AzureAD` to import it manually.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230784/discussion-between-s-a-n-and-joy-wang).

Comment: @s-a-n I don't know what you mean `unfortunately doesnt seem to work for me`, just run a powershell session as administrator, run `Update-Module -Name AzureAD -Force`, then close all the powershell sessions, open a new one, run `Connect-AzureAD` and that command, it will work.

Comment: Did all the above still couldn't find the cmdlet error.

Comment: @s-a-n Did you check your AzureAD module version?

Comment: yep 2.0.2.130 , AzureAD - this is when i got Get-InstalledModule. But when I do Get-Module I dont see AzureAD at all and when I do import, it says its already loaded.

Comment: @s-a-n Try to close all the powershell sessions and open a new one, run the command `Connect-AzureAD` again.

Comment: Sure @joy, have you tried this in Azure cloudshell?

Comment: @s-a-n It will not work in cloudshell, cloudshell uses `AzureAD.Standard.Preview` module, it does not have this command.

Comment: Ah thats where I have been trying, is there a way to make it work in cloud shell?

Comment: @s-a-n No, you could not use it in cloudshell, even if you can install `AzureAD` module, there is a conflict with `AzureAD.Standard.Preview`, just try that locally.

Comment: Locally works great, thank you for all the prolonged conv, much appreciate @joy!

Answer (score 1):

The AAD app type property should be `-SignInAudience`. But it's read-only in AAD PowerShell.

So the workaround is to call Microsoft Graph to modify this property.

A sample for your reference (Modify **{client_id}**, **{client_secret}** and **{tenant_id}** to yours, and give `Application.ReadWrite.All` application permission to your app registration as per [Update application permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions)):

```
Connect-AzureAD

$App = New-AzureADApplication -DisplayName "PSMultiApp02"

$boundary = [System.Guid]::NewGuid().ToString(); 
$LF = "`r`n";

$bodyLines = ( 
    "--$boundary",
    "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=`"grant_type`"$LF",
    "client_credentials$LF",
    "--$boundary",
    "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=`"client_id`"$LF",
    "{client_id}$LF",
    "--$boundary",
    "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=`"scope`"$LF",
    "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default$LF",
    "--$boundary",
    "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=`"client_secret`"$LF",
    "{client_secret}$LF",
    "--$boundary--$LF" 
) -join $LF

$AuthTokenRequestHeaders = @{
    "Cache-Control" = "no-cache"
}

$AuthTokenResponse = Invoke-RestMethod 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/v2.0/token' -Method 'POST' -ContentType "multipart/form-data; boundary=`"$boundary`"" -Body $bodyLines -Headers $AuthTokenRequestHeaders

$authToken = $AuthTokenResponse.access_token

$headers = @{ }
$headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")
$headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer $($authToken)")

$postData = "{
    `"signInAudience`":`"AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount`",
    `"api`":{`"requestedAccessTokenVersion`": 2}
}";

$requestURI = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/$($App.ObjectId)"

$Result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $requestURI -Method PATCH -Headers $headers -Body $postData
```

Comment: Thanks @allen, I was more looking for a powershell command to achieve this. I am trying to test with New-AzureADMSApplication. hope this works!