# New-AzureADApplication : Not able to create app registraion by providing SignInAudience property in azure active directory

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-powershell

I am running below command from powershell. I want to create app registraion using SignInAudience as mentioned below. But I am not able to do this as getting error saying that SignInAudience is readonly. But this is not mentioned anywhere in ms documentation.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/new-azureadapplication?view=azureadps-2.0

**Connect-AzureAD -TenantId "3433191-6b37-34325-9e6b-e631ac3434347"

$aadApplications = New-AzureADApplication -DisplayName "MyTestApp20001" -SignInAudience "AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount"**

I also tried to update the existing application using below command but still getting the same error

## Get the application to modify

$app = Get-AzureADApplication -Filter "DisplayName eq 'MyTestApp20001'"
Write-Host "Finished $($app)" -ForegroundColor Yellow
 
Set-AzureADApplication -ObjectId $app.ObjectId -SignInAudience "AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount"

Error : Set-AzureADApplication : Error occurred while executing SetApplication
Code: Request_BadRequest
Message: Property 'signInAudience' is read-only and cannot be set.
RequestId: 8441bb12-333f-4dac-9bc6-2f3e25d75a2a
DateTimeStamp: Fri, 14 Apr 2023 17:47:40 GMT
HttpStatusCode: BadRequest
HttpStatusDescription: Bad Request
HttpResponseStatus: Completed
At line:7 char:1

- Set-AzureADApplication -ObjectId $app.ObjectId -SignInAudience "Azure ...
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Set-AzureADApplication], ApiException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Open.AzureAD16.Client.ApiException,Microsoft.Open.AzureAD16.PowerShell.SetApplication
  ```

I tried my best to solve the problem. I refer the microsoft link but i am not able to make it.
My expectation is Create application from powershell using AzureAd. I want when we create application we can set one of its property SignInCredential.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results:***

When I ran same commands as you to create Azure AD application with `SignInAudience` as "AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount", I got **same error** as below:

```
Connect-AzureAD 
New-AzureADApplication -DisplayName "MyTestApp20001" -SignInAudience "AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount"
```

**Response:**

[image]

You are getting that error as `New-AzureADApplication` calls **Azure AD Graph** that is currently deprecated.

Alternatively, make use of below command that calls **Microsoft Graph** directly to create Azure AD application.

```
New-AzureADMSApplication -DisplayName "MyTestApp20001" -SignInAudience "AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount"
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I checked the same in Portal, application created successfully with `SignInAudience` as *"AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount"* like below:

[image]

**Reference:**
[Azure AD App Registration for Multi tenant and Personal accounts using powershell by **Joy Wang**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66927678/azure-ad-app-registration-for-multi-tenant-and-personal-accounts-using-powershel)